# QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission requirements?

Tags: android, permissions, package, android-permissions

What are the requirements of newly added `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission?

Like, is adding it to manifest enough (like with internet-permission), or do I need to show dialog for said permission, like we do for storage-permission (in newer Android-versions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` has a protection level of `normal`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES), so all that you need in the app itself is the manifest entry.

Note that your desired app distribution channel may require you to complete a form documenting why you feel that your app needs this permission, and they may elect to not distribute your app.

Comment: Android's `VpnService` provides API to exclude Apps from being routed, which a lot of VPN-Apps use, to allow users to choose what data to protect and what not (hence let's hope they make an exception, and don't simply reject the App through bot, programmatically).

Comment: We also tried ```:                                                                                                    
<queries>                                                                                                                                         
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />                                         
</queries>                                                                                                                                    ```

but seems `queries` does not support `uses-permission` yet (if will ever).